# OrderBy working but not where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**This works fine.**

```
$q=Question::with(['users'=>function($query)
    {
        $query->orderBy('pivot_approved','desc');
    }])->get();
```

**This doesnot:**

```
 $q=Question::with(['users'=>function($query)
        {
            $query->where('pivot_approved',1);
        }])->get();
```

Also tried with wherePivot in the relation:

```
public function users()
{     
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','question_user','q_id','user_id')->wherePivot('approved',1);  
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the result you are expecting from the query?

Comment: @Armin I want to display questions and the users where `approved` column in `question_user` table is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add [`withPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to the relation first:

```
->withPivot('approved');
```

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship